How do I use pre-defined coordinates to draw angles with TikZ?
I'm trying to draw a vector on a set of axes and label it with a theta symbol for physics homework.  According to the TikZ docs, I need three coordinates to draw an angle.  Using this stack answer, it looks like I can define several coordinates, and use them as I please in the angle command.  So I wrote this:
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (negx) at (-5,0);
\coordinate (veca) at (-2.4075, 3.1945);

\draw[<->,ultra thick] (-5,0) coordinate (A) --(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[<->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw[->, thick] (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (-2.4075, 3.1945) coordinate (C) node[left]{\textbf{A}};

 pic [$\theta$, draw, ->] {angle = negx--origin--veca};
\end{tikzpicture}

However, my output looks like this:

How do I get the angle symbol to appear?  I don't want to have to draw a three-sided thingy - I'd like to be able to draw the angle between the two-pointed vector and the negative-x axis underneath.

\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (negx) at (-5,0);
\coordinate (veca) at (-2.4075, 3.1945);

\draw[<->,ultra thick] (-5,0) coordinate (A) --(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[<->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw[->, thick] (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (-2.4075, 3.1945) coordinate (C) node[left]{\textbf{A}};

% Notice the quotes aorund the label
\draw pic["$\theta$", draw, <-,angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle = veca--origin--negx};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


